# ViewHolder in RecyclerView.Adapter not specific to position

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

The following is part of my code for `onBindViewHolder` (inside `MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>`)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    StatusItem item = mDataset.get(position);
    //......
    //Add content and timing to the textview
    String content = item.getContent();

    holder.mTextViewTime.setText(timing);
    //Set the img
    holder.imgViewIcon.setImageDrawable(item.getProfileDrawable());
    //Set content image (for Instagram)
    holder.mImageViewContentPic.setImageDrawable(item.getContentDrawable());
    //HIDE THE VIEW Start
    if(item.getContentDrawable() == null){
        holder.mImageViewContentPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    //HIDE THE VIEW End
}
```

The part `HIDE THE VIEW` is not working as expected.
When I am scrolling downwards, the views are working normally. However, when I start to scroll upwards, i.e. revisited the previous views, the ImageViews that are supposed to be `VISIBLE` becomes `GONE`, although I checked my dataset and verified that it has not been modified. Try calling other methods on the views also give erratic results(positions and items in dataset do not match).

It seems that the view holders are not binded to specific positions inside the RecyclerView.

The code works as expected if I remove the `HIDE THE VIEW` part.
Is there any way to solve this issue and dynamically hide views in my case?

Note: I used some AsyncTasks to update the dataset and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, if that is relevant.

Comment: ViewHolder is not supposed to be specific to position. I.e if you have 100 items there are no 100 ViewHolders. Override bindView method (I cannot remember the exact name) in adapter to change visibility in regard to position instead.

Comment: Can't seem to find such method in `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
###This is the solution to your problem:###

holder.mImageViewContentPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if(item.getContentDrawable() == null){
        holder.mImageViewContentPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Can explain further as to why this works?

Comment: This is the case with the implementation of view holder pattern. It uses same view every time or you can it reuses the view, so the view ones gone will remain gone that why you have to make it visible again. There are many tricks to work with these reusable views and hope you will find them in near future.

Comment: Was facing a similar problem as @paradite. Have download, cancel buttons and progress bars inside the view. After making the buttons GONE for one VH, subsequent view holders would show/not-show the buttons randomly. Though, I figured this was caused due to views being recycled, couldn't quite figure out a solution. Your tip just saved lots more hours of mine. Thanks.

Comment: CHEERS DUDE. YOU SAVED MY ASS

Answer (score 0):

Because `RecyclerView` use recycle very well, `ViewHolder` A may be used to be `ViewHolder` B, so you need to specific every attribute of a `ViewHolder` in case of some attributes attach to a wrong object.